# Use AWS wrangler without AWS cli

Tags: python, amazon-athena, aws-data-wrangler

I'm running the following code through AWS wrangler

```
import awswrangler as wr

my_query = wr.athena.read_sql_query(
    sql="""select "$path" as path from table""",
    database='db', workgroup='workgroup'
)
```

But I don't wish to use static methods such as `Aws Cli` or `configurations` file to store my creds.

How do I add the creds directly in the above code?

Answer (score 1):

I had to create a boto3 session and pass it as a parameter value

```
my_session = boto3.Session(region_name="REGION", \  
aws_access_key_id="YOUR_ACCESS_KEY", aws_secret_access_key="YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")

my_query = wr.athena.read_sql_query(
    sql="""select "$path" as path from table""",
    database='db', workgroup='workgroup',
    boto3_session= my_session
)
```